# Testing NativeScript app with Appium

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, appium, nativescript

I am learning NativeScript. I am trying to write some automated tests with Jasmine. From my understanding, I can use [Appium](http://appium.io/) with Jasmine to run automated tests in the emulator. At this time, I've added the [appium-gulp-plugins](https://github.com/appium/appium-gulp-plugins) to my package.son file. I also have a basic JavaScript file with a single test. That file looks like this:

```
describe('MyApp', function() {
  describe('Login', function() {
    it('should successfuly login', function() {
      // set username field value
      // set password field value
      // click "login" button.
      // get response.
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });           
  });        
});
```

I have two challenges:

1. How do I interact with the NativeScript view from the test?
2. How do I actually run the tests? As it is right now, its just straight up Jasmine, so I can do the following:

   ```
   gulp.src('./path/to/tests.js').pipe(jasmine());
   ```

However, with Appium in the mix, I'm not sure how to integrate it as part of running my tests.

Comment: It looks like you can't: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/553

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Part-1** : Views are created using xml which must have attributes like `text,name,css` etc. These are accessible using methods like `By.name,By.cssSelector` [etc.](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) depending on the attributes provided during development.

**Part-2** :  I believe since Appium was built on selenium initially and supports majority of its functionality. You can go ahead and try something similar to [this](http://engineering.wingify.com/posts/e2e-testing-with-webdriverjs-jasmine/) and you can provide action to your suite accessing the objects as in Part-1. To run the tests created would require similar efforts to run your main test script.

Answer (score 4):

Look this closed issue at github: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/553

You don't have access to internals of your app :( (when you use appium for tests, but why you don't take a look in [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF), you access elements by using accessibility label or accessibility identifier, it's more simple. Hope helps :)

Comment: would appreciate if you could quote specific info from the links shared